# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular application i'm getting this error

**" Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**

[image]

I'm not able to find the issue in my code.
The only place where I'm using name is a select

Below is the HTML of the select component at Line 24

```
<section *ngIf="setPlainHeader" class="p-l-xxl p-r-xxl p-b-md category bg-white-only box-shadow">
  <div class="form-group nav navbar-nav navbar-btn m-t-xs m-b-xs">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label  p-t-xs m-t-xs">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 p-t-xs">
      <select
        *ngIf="Categories"
        (change)="categoryChange()"
        name="category"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory"
        class="form-control">
        <option
          *ngFor="let item of Categories | async "
          [value]="item.categoryId" label="">
          {{item?.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Below is the code in ts

```
selectedCategory: any = '-1';

ngOnInit() {
  this.Categories=this.commonServ.getCategoryData()
}

categoryChange() {
  this.commonServ.setSelectedCategory(this.selectedCategory); 
}
```

The categories load but in the console i keep getting this error which is causing some other issues in rendering.

EDIT:I tried to narrow down the issue 
the section in the  header is visible on certain pages using **setPlainHeader**.So when the element(section) gets hidden/visible i get this error.

Can anyone guide me what exactly needs to be done.

Thanks

Comment: try this {{item?.name}}

Comment: is that worked for you ???

Answer (score 0):

Try using safe navigation `?` operator like this -

```
{{item?.name}}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with the *ngIf="setPlainHeader"

So i changed my code and added a timeout which assigning the value to setPlainHeader

```
this.abcService.getHeaderStatus().subscribe(
        data => {
          setTimeout(function () {

            self.setPlainHeader = data;
          }, 100);


        });
```

This worked and finally the error is gone.

Thanks

Comment: its wrong solution , why you need that as you already have *ngIF